# InsertOnSubmit equivalent in DbContext.DbSet using Entity Framework 4 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using entity framework code first approach, and I am building a generic Repository class that provides data access. In this class I want an `Add(T entity)` method. However, there is no `InsertOnSubmit` method as part of the `DbSet<T>` class, and if I try to use the `Add` method, I get a compile time error:

```
The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'
```

This is the method:

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
     return _database.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
}
```

Anyone know a way to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: for personal use, could i ask you what "_database" is in your application? I'm trying to make a method like yours and it complains about the Set method.. Thank you in advance!

Comment: yeh man, the _database field is of type DbContext, which is found in the entity framework. have a look at ScotGu's blog about using entity framework 4 code first approach, it's really simple: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I take a read.. I have a bonus question :P the .Set method, what is the code for that? I took a very quick in the articel, and didn't spot that method. That is the last part of the code i need to get my project done. You are more than welcome to get my mail if you sent me the .Set  method code. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a generic constraint to your repository class:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

Answer (score 5):

I have literally just posted this question but I have found a way around the problem - use the Set(Type t) method instead of the generic version like so:

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
   return (TEntity)_database.Set(typeof(TEntity)).Add(entity);
}
```

A little bit of intellisense inspection goes a long way! Hope this helps someone...