# Get collection property of a specific type

Tags: c#

I have a class MyDatabaseContext that has a series of DbSet collection properties:

```
public DbSet<EntityA> EntitiesA { get; set; }
public DbSet<EntityB> EntitiesB { get; set; }
public DbSet<EntityC> EntitiesC { get; set; }
```

I need to get the name of the collection given the type of the entity.
For example, I have "EntityB" and want to get as a result "EntitiesB".

I really wanted to avoid switch-case statements, since MyDatabaseContext is generated automatically (T4 templates).

Comment: why do you need the name of the property?

Comment: Good point. The type `EntityC` of variable `EntitiesC` should be widely available, even at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the name of the property here you go. I would just refine the answer given by hunter. You can use the same method with string as return type.

```
    public string GetEntitiName<T>() where T : class
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(MyDatabaseContext).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<T>)).FirstOrDefault();
        string propertyName = propInfo.Name; //The string has the property name ..
        return propertyName;    
    }
```

I tried a sample similar to your situation. Try replacing List with DbSet.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void GetEntities<T>() where T : class
        {

            var info = typeof(TestClass1).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(List<T>));

            Console.WriteLine(info.FirstOrDefault().Name);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetEntities<int>();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class TestClass1
    {
        public List<int> IntTest { get; set; }
        public List<double> DoubleTest { get; set; }
        public List<string> IStringTest { get; set; }
    }
```

This sample works.

Comment: I get this error on typeof(DbSet<T>): The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>'

Comment: If you want to use typeof on a generic type definition you need to do it with empty <>, like: typeof(Dictionary<,>)

Comment: i am using that inside a Generic method so that should work right?

Comment: With type List it works. When I change it to DbSet (EF4.1), I get the error above.

Comment: Try giving a generic constraint to the generic method GenericEntities<T> where T: class . And you can use only reference types.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Also just found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621253/insertonsubmit-equivalent-in-dbcontext-dbset-using-entity-framework-4-code-first

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old page, But my answer maybe useful for other guys referring here. (like me)

I think you want to accessing `EntitiesB` to run a query on it, like `EntitiesB.Where(a=>a.bla=="blabla")`. If I'm right or another visitor of this page needs something like this, just easily use the following code:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;

((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<EntityB>()
```

Description:

```
_dbContext is Context class inherting from DbContext.
EntitiesB is DbSet<EntityB> defined in Context class.
```

Example:

```
Ilist result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<EntityB>().Where(b=>b.bla=="blabla").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generated file is a partial class, you could create a new file and declare a class with same name using the keyword `partial`, then make a method which will return the desired Collection...

Comment: but then I would have to go the switch-case route, that I really wanted to avoid...

Comment: I don't see other options here... but you could: 1. Use one context in each file (multiple edmx). 2. Make it generate a `class<T>` and have a property `DbSet<T>`. Sorry if that doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this myself, but it sounds like what you want to do is to use reflection to locate the property of type "DbSet" that has the appropriate generic type parameter. The following pseudo-C# should get you started:

```
foreach ( FieldInfo field in this.GetType() )
{
  if ( field.FieldType.IsGenericType )
  {
    foreach ( Type param in field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments() )
    {
      if ( param.Name == soughtType )
      {
        return field.Name;
      }
    }
  }
}
```