# Entity Framework equivalent of InsertonSubmit

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621253/insertonsubmit-equivalent-in-dbcontext-dbset-using-entity-framework-4-code-first) with basically the same header but is different in my case. I moved from Linq-to-SQL to Entity Framework (which I am a little new to) and I have a method where I use `InsertOnSubmit`, and so I found out it is in Linq-to-SQL and not in Entity Framework, any ideas?

Linq-to-SQL:

```
  dc.tblTruckDetails.InsertOnSubmit(tblInsert);
  dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call `InsertOnSubmit` in Entity Framework.

You can simply create a `new object` of what you want to `add` in database and then call `SaveChanges` method.

```
Entities entities = new Entities();

Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Name = "Mairaj";

entities.Employees.Add(emp);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes Thank you I will look more carefully next time before posting question @MairajAhmed

Answer (score 1):

I know I just posted the Question but I it is actually very straight forward.

```
db.TruckCheckin.Add(result);
db.SaveChanges();
```